# Need to press f12 for selecting os every time i boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bios

Hi i have two Operating Systems installed,both on different hard disks .One is ubntu 14.04 and other one is windows 10. When I start my system , I always have to hold down F12 for selecting which Operating System I want to boot from.I'm doing that using the motherboard's BIOS.But if i don't hold down F12 ,it will go ahead and boot the from the device which has the first preference.I want it to ask me every time which os i want to boot without me having to press f12 .

Comment: Do you have grub installed ?

Comment: Chances are either you have a mixed-mode (EFI/BIOS) installation or your firmware is defective. Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/), post the `RESULTS.txt` file to [a pastebin site,](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL here for us to analyze. Without that information, any answer will be based on an assumption about the cause, and that assumption might or might not be correct.

Answer (score 2):

In the BIOS settings, under "Boot options" (or similarly named option), choose HDD on which you have Ubuntu installed as the Default boot device. Save the changes.

This should automatically make your system boot into Ubuntu. Before starting Ubuntu, it might show you the option to start Windows as well (usually the last option). See below.

[image: Like on this image.]

If Ubuntu starts, but does not give you the option to boot into Windows, then while in Ubuntu, open the terminal and use this command to update GRUB settings:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot and check if you can see Windows option now.

Comment: I was just about to write the same! ;-)

Comment: Well, sorry about that. :P

Comment: No need to be sorry, you were faster and it's a good answer. Congratulations!